# Why Gulp does not ignore the file?

Tags: node.js, gulp, frontend

My project structure:

```
build
public
    assets
        css
            app.css
            vendor.css
        js
            app.js
            vendor.js
    index.html
src
    assets
        styles
            main.styl
        coffee
            main.coffee
    index.jade
```

I have a task to build a library of Bower in two files : vendor.css and vendor.js:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('bower', ['clean'], function () {
  var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src('./bower.json')
    .pipe(mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)

    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)

    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Here's my task on cleaning of temporary folders when you change files in the src folder:

```
var del = require('del');
...
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del(['build', 'public/**', '!public/**/vendor.{js,css}']);
});
```

That must delete the build folder and all the contents of the public directory, except the vendor.css and vendor.js that are in the folder public/assets/css and public/assets/js.

This is done in order to not build a library of bower at each change of the file, because it takes 3-4 seconds (by the way, is this normal?), but only at the first start or change bower.json ( running separate watcher).

But somehow, the files vendor.js and vendor.css also removed. With [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap) I got a list of files:
[List of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvHKb.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/sindresorhus/del#beware you need also exclude sub-directories, otherwise `del` will delete all.

So, you can use something like this:

```
del([.., 'public/**/*', '!public/{dir_1,dir_2}', '!test/**/vendor{.css,.js}']);
```